# Ability to cut AWS services when a budget is exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm new to AWS and I would like to know if it's possible to cut off all services when a budget is exceeded? Indeed, in case of uncontrollable costs, this could jeopardize my company.

I saw that it's possible to set alarms and alerts, but what I'm really looking for is to cut off the services to stop the billing. I found some documentation on how to do it with Lambdas, but I wanted to know beforehand if AWS hasn't implemented a setting somewhere to do this natively

Comment: Are you currently experiencing high charges? If so, which services are causing the expenses? Or are you just worried about potential costs in future? What services are you using?

Comment: I am only worried about future costs; it's just in case because it's a risk that cannot be taken for my business.

Comment: Related discussion [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/xv4fs4/aws_shutdown_ec2_on_budget_alert/).

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no single option to "cut off services".

Please note that some costs are related to API requests (eg GetObject from S3), some are related to time (eg Amazon EC2 instance running time) and some are due to storage quantity and time (eg GB/month for objects in S3 and EBS volumes in EC2). So, stopping all costs would need to involve terminating instances and deleting objects from S3, which is probably not what you would like to do.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought, indeed I have S3s that shouldn't be cut, and I suppose it's also not possible to cut this or that service in case of budget overrun without going through lambdas?

Comment: There is no in-built capability that automatically stops services when a budget is exceeded. You could code something up that responds to billing information or alerts, but that is up to you to implement (either using AWS Lambda functions or code running elsewhere).